# uib-datepicker-popup Not showing picker in firefox or safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I been using the Ui angular bootstrap datepicker, and it's been working fine.... in chrome.

As it turn out, Firefox and safari won't show the datepicker. Anyone ever run into this before.

my HTML looks like this

```
 <p class="input-group">
       <input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="startDate" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Close" />
 </p>
```

And my JS/Controller looks like this

```
   $scope.today = function () {
        $scope.startDate = new Date();
        $scope.startDate.setMonth($scope.startDate.getMonth() - 1);
        $scope.endDate = new Date();
        $scope.endDate.setMonth($scope.endDate.getMonth() + 1);
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function (date, mode) {
        return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
    };


    $scope.open = function ($event) {
        $scope.status.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.setDate = function (year, month, day) {
        $scope.startDate = new Date(year, month, day);
        $scope.endDate = new Date(year, month, day);
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

    $scope.status = {
        opened: false
    };
```

As told before This works. But in firefox and safari, it's not showing the datepicker, but it does so in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which version of `UI Bootstrap` you are using but in 1.2.4 the datepicker markup looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="startDate" is-open="opened" ... />
```

tried your code in FF 44 and IE 11 - seems fine to me: http://plnkr.co/edit/deE1lR?p=preview

Comment: I allso tried using with the uib-datepicker-popup. but i don't have the button to show the popup like you have. in mine code, it's just a arrow in the input field. maybe this is what making it work. gonna try it out. be right back

Comment: Show out that if i use the type input="date" it works different. so i change the  datepicker back to uib-datepicker and type from date to text, an now it's works. thanks

Comment: apparently firefox and IE trie to show thier own datepickers if the input type is set to **date** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date